# parse javascript variable in .net getElementById?

Tags: javascript, vb.net

I feel like I already know the answer to this is going to be "not possible" but just in case.

Let's say I have this javascript function used to read .net webform field's value:

```
function getById(theId) {
 return  document.getElementById(theId).value;
}
```

which I can call like this:

```
getById("<%=txtField1.ClientID%>");
```

Ok, that works fine.

But it is a given that .ClientID is always going to be in there, which means this function *could* be whittled down, but only if it is possible to represent the form field as a variable by itself.  Something like this:

```
function getById(fieldName) {
 return  document.getElementById(<%= + fieldName + .ClientID%>).value;
}
```

to be called like this (much cleaner)...

```
    getById("txtField1");
```

Is this possible?

Comment: `txtField1.ClientID` is server-side code.  It gets turned into a string by the dotnet server long before the javascript parser is even fired up.  You can't execute server-side code from the browser without sending a new http request of some kind.

Comment: Yes, but I thought perhaps there was something that could be worked out from codebehind then brought forward and into the javascript when needed.

I'm guessing that would be more hassle than it is worth, if it's even possible.

Answer (score 0):

Well yes and no/maybe.

Yes Part: 
JS order of operations supports the ability to append strings before the get element call. For example if I had a textbox with id "searchTerm" then I could do this in js and be absolutely fine:

var check = document.getElementById('search' + 'Term').value;

NO Part: unless webforms differs significantly than what I remember way back when, that original function you have there is created to specifically get values when js is called inline and is about as optimized as you are going to get for that action. Once the page is loaded all of those server side variables will no longer be available for javascript and you would have to use the true client side elements IDs. Once workaround I suppose is to add onClick action to pass the client side ID such like so

```
<input type="text" onClick="WhatIsLove(this.id)" value="BabyDontHurtMe" id="Sing">
```